# CollapsingToolbarLayout elevation not showing

Tags: android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, elevation, android-elevation

I have a programmatically added collapsingToolbarLayout. For some reason, I do not see the elevation, either in its collapsed or expanded state.
I've tried the following to no avail:

```
Resources r = getResources();
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)collapsingToolbarLayout.getParent();

/* none of these work */
ViewCompat.setElevation(collapsingToolbarLayout,r.getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation));
ViewCompat.setElevation(appBarLayout, r.getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation));
ViewCompat.setElevation(getPrimaryToolbar(), r.getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation));
```

Would there be a reason for this?